ETH transaction pending for more than 12 days
I have a transaction pending on ETH which is bridging ETH to Base and Blast mainnet. Below are the transaction hashes.
0x9499ba0390b11645fb551b549f73047485a5bcfa171fb32e60f561e082d5c494
0x70eb5d90bfe6ef41ac17326c2e61b5bb139df5186d3cd877cd4119a7ecb512c3 (In etherscan it says that the transaction cannot be found)
I may have provided low gas fee, but I have tried to cancel the transaction by paying high fee and it still hasn't gone through.
Is there anything I can do or wait indefinitely?

The replacement transaction should use the same nonce and a higher gas price. As of 2024-04-12 15:23:00 UTC the average price of block 19,640,226 is 27 gwei. If you want to replace the transaction check https://etherscan.io/gastracker for the suggested gas prices.
